# SQLite database crashes on creation

Tags: sqlite, android-studio

I'm setting up an application that receives information from a user in the MainActivity, transfers it so the SecondActivity which shows the info on a view list.

I tried looking for the main factor that causes the issue and I found it was the Database Builder, could not found what causes it.

```
public class HelperDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final String TABLE_CONTACT="Contact";
    public static final String TABLE_USER = "User";

    String strCreate, strDelete;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public HelperDB(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        strCreate="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_USER;
        strCreate+= " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCRENEMT,";
        strCreate+= " "+NAME+" TEXT,";
        strCreate+= " "+AGE+" INTEGER";
        strCreate+= ");";
        db.execSQL(strCreate);

        strCreate="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_CONTACT;
        strCreate+= " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCRENEMT,";
        strCreate+=" "+PHONE+" TEXT,";
        strCreate+=" "+EMAIL+" TEXT,";
        strCreate+=" "+IDENTITY+" TEXT";
        strCreate+=");";
        db.execSQL(strCreate);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    strDelete="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_USER;
    db.execSQL(strDelete);
    strDelete="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_CONTACT;
    db.execSQL(strDelete);

    onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

When I am creating the HelperDB on my MainActivity, it crashes in the part that inserted on the OnCreate section :-

```
     hlp=new HelperDB(this);
     db=hlp.getWritableDatabase();
     db.close();
```

The application keeps on crashing when I delete the HelperDB build the application works fine. Please help me find a solution for that.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the Stack-Trace. See [Debug your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/) if you do not know how.

Comment: Try uninstalling the App and re-running the App, does the issue still happen (if so add the Stack Trace as per previous comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong keyword. **AUTOINCRENEMT** should be **AUTOINCREMENT** (both uses).

However, it is suggested that you don't code AUTOINCREMENT, it's inefficient and virtually definitely not required. As per :- [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Which includes :-

> ## Summary
>
> **The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly
> needed. It is usually not needed.**
>
> In SQLite, a column with type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is an alias for the
> ROWID (except in WITHOUT ROWID tables) which is always a 64-bit signed
> integer.
>
> On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not
> explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an
> unused integer, usually one more than the largest ROWID currently in
> use. This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT
> keyword is used.
>
> If the AUTOINCREMENT keyword appears after INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, that
> changes the automatic ROWID assignment algorithm to prevent the reuse
> of ROWIDs over the lifetime of the database. In other words, the
> purpose of AUTOINCREMENT is to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs from
> previously deleted rows.

Using `column_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` will effectively be the same, that is when a row is inserted without specifying a value for the **_id** column, it will be given a unique number that will generally increment by 1 (no guarantee for either with or without AUTOINCREMENT).

- All that AUTOINCREMENT does, at some expense, is to ensure that the number is greater than the highest number used to date. This will be the case anyway until 9223372036854775807 rows have been added, when :-
- if AUTOINCREMENT is coded an SQLITE_FULL excpetion will occur.
- if AUTOINCREMENT isn't coded then attempts are made to allocate an unused number.
- However, with AUTOINCREMENT, a second system table **sqlite_sequence** will be involved. This stores the highest used number so the value that is the greater of the highest **rowid** or the value of the respective row in the sqlite_sequqnce table + 1. Rather than the highest value of **rowid** + 1.

  - note `column_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY' (with or without AUTOINCREMENT defines the column as an alias of the **rowid** column, a normally hidden column).

## The Fix (suggested)

As such the following is a suggested fix :-

```
public class HelperDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final String TABLE_CONTACT="Contact";
    public static final String TABLE_USER = "User";

    String strCreate, strDelete;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public HelperDB(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        strCreate="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_USER;
        strCreate+= " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,";
        strCreate+= " "+NAME+" TEXT,";
        strCreate+= " "+AGE+" INTEGER";
        strCreate+= ");";
        db.execSQL(strCreate);

        strCreate="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_CONTACT;
        strCreate+= " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,";
        strCreate+=" "+PHONE+" TEXT,";
        strCreate+=" "+EMAIL+" TEXT,";
        strCreate+=" "+IDENTITY+" TEXT";
        strCreate+=");";
        db.execSQL(strCreate);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    strDelete="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_USER;
    db.execSQL(strDelete);
    strDelete="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_CONTACT;
    db.execSQL(strDelete);

    onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

- **Note** as you already run the App, the database (albeit without any tables) will still exists so the **onCreate** method will not run. As such you would need to do one of the following after you have changed the CREATE TABLE SQL for both tables:-
- Delete/Clear the App's data.
- Uninstall the App.
- Increase the Database Version number (e.g. change `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;` to `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;`

After doing one of the above you can then rerun the App.

P.S. The stack-trace would have been along the lines of :-

```
2018-12-30 11:11:41.029 3278-3278/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "AUTOINCRENEMT": syntax error
2018-12-30 11:11:41.030 3278-3278/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2018-12-30 11:11:41.032 3278-3278/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: so53958115.so53958115, PID: 3278
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{so53958115.so53958115/so53958115.so53958115.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTOINCRENEMT": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE User (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCRENEMT, name TEXT, age INTEGER);
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2914)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTOINCRENEMT": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE User (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCRENEMT, name TEXT, age INTEGER);
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1769)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1698)
        at so53958115.so53958115.HelperDB.onCreate(HelperDB.java:34)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:393)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:298)
        at so53958115.so53958115.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2894)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Thanks, Forpas and MikeT. I got my mistake, or my teacher's mistake ugh.